# What bonuses do I get if I play The Surge with a lot of tech scrap on hand?

Tags: the-surge

I see a tip on the loading screen that says there are benefits to playing with a lot of tech scrap on hand.

What exactly are the benefits?

Comment: I know there are achievements for carrying scrap, including one for holding a high amount, and one for defeating an area boss with more than 60k scrap.  Still new so there may be more reasons

Answer (score 2):

1. There are 2 achievements related to number of Tech Scrap carried:

> **Nothing to Lose**: Carried more than 50,000 Tech Scrap
>
> **Overconfident**: Defeated a boss while carrying at least 20,000 Tech Scrap

2. There is some buff awarded:

   > Whenever you finish off an enemy, there is a chance to trigger a stamina regeneration buff. The more scrap you currently carry, the higher the chance the buff procs.
3. And there are injectable recharges and energy fill-ups:

   > You actually get awarded implant injections whenever you fill up your tech scrap bar (there is actually a bar appearing while scrap is being awarded which fills up, it's corresponding to the scrap you need to level up). If you don't have injectable implants equipped (or you did not use any charges), you will be awarded with a full energy bar instead with a pretty long decay delay (precious energy that you could use to charge up your drone or use energy based implants, for example).

Sources: [patch notes](https://steamcommunity.com/games/378540/announcements/detail/1272677539198140548), [dev post 1](https://steamcommunity.com/app/378540/discussions/0/1290690669221499552/#c1290690669221847836), [dev post 2](https://steamcommunity.com/app/378540/discussions/0/1290690669221499552/?ctp=2#c1290690669224124185).